# Localised names for directories in mac os x

Tags: macos, localization, nsopenpanel

I have set `/Volume` directory to `NSOpenPanel` so when user try to browse using `NSOpenPanel` it shows all volumes to user.
Issue : Is `/Volumes` folder name is same for all languages or I need to add localisation value for english name "`/Volumes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched my language to French and then to Chinese, and both times the absolute directory names remained the same. The screenshot below shows this. So, to echo what @mschmidt said in the comments, it looks like localized names are only displayed to the user. They are not used in the filesystem, so folder names will remain the same when switching languages. [image: directory names remain the same when switching languages on macOS]

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly, but the path or URL you provide to `NSOpenPanel` is just a non-localized path as you see in in Terminal.

Comment: @mschmidt I have provided hardcoded path @"/Volumes to NSOpenPanel, As I select english language at beginning all directories have names in english. like /Application /System..but suppose if user select Chinese/French language at beginning is all directories have same names or localised version of names.

Comment: @Sangram, don't worry. `/Volumes` is correct. Localized names are only displayed to the user. They are not used in the filesystem.